# Decompose a dataset of 800 variables with their individual weekly and monthly component by a loop in R

Tags: r

We got a large dataset which we want to decompose with a loop.
The problem is to write a loop where a new variable is selected for each loop and applied with a decompose.

Current code which decompose all variables with the same day-weekly component:

```
library(fpp)    
news_ts = ts(news, frequency = 5, start = c(2016,1), end = c(2019,1))    
decompose_news = decompose(news_ts, "additive")    
adjust_news = ts_test - decompose_news$seasonal
```

Comment: This gives `data(news)
Warning message:
In data(news) : data set ‘news’ not found`.

Comment: have you had a look at `apply` or `purrr:map`. As I understand it, you are trying to apply a function over a vector of values?

Comment: The same for `ts_test`. It is not defined in your posted code.

Comment: Rui, thanks for the answer. the ts_test was wrongly named. I have corrected the code. My bad.